# Code::Blocks - Program crashing with 255 exit code

Tags: c++, combinations

I'm writing a simple program to make a Pascal's triangle. It uses the idea that: 
C(i, j+1)=C(i, j)*(i-j)/(j+1).
The program computes each next term recursively from the previous one, using this formula. Here's the code:

```
include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rows, now = 1;

    cout << "Number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;

    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        now = 1;
        cout << i;
        for (int ii = 0; ii <= rows - i; ii++)
            cout << " ";

        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << now << " ";
            now = (now *(i - j)) / j+1;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program stops after writing the 0th row,  with a Windows monit, and after I click "close program" it retrurns 255. Please help!

Note: I first had i, j going from 1 and (i-j)/j instead of (i-j)/(j+1) and it worked, but I want it to compute exactly C(i, j+1) for every i and j, not C(i+1, j+1) as it was before.

Comment: You need to take `j + 1` into parenthesis when divide.

Comment: Thanks! That's why I like algorithms, but certainly not C++ :)